# Fast clicking breaks jQuery toggle()

Tags: jquery

This works as it should except if you click on the same label many times fast it breaks the `toggle()`. I expect this behavior as `toggle()` working as it should. The question is: How do I make it so that the `toggle()` doesn't run if the element is already `:checked`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#UPLOADMYDESIGNFF").show();

$('label').click(function() {
     
     var total = 0;
     
      $('.option:checked').each(function() {

     if( $(this).is('#DESIGNONLYFF:checked, #NOPRINTFF:checked')) 
                {
                  $("#UPLOADMYDESIGNFF").toggle();
                }


      total += parseFloat($(this).data('number'));  
      $(this).parent().addClass('cust-selected-cart-item');
          
      });

      $('.option:not(:checked)').each(function() {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('cust-selected-cart-item');
      });
          
          $('.sub-total-t').html('$' + total.toFixed(2) );
      });
      
      
  });
```

Of coarse the default for DIV:`UPLOADMYDESIGNFF` is set to `DISPLAY:NONE`

## HTML

```
<label><input id="NOPRINTFF" type="radio" name="print"/></label>
<label><input id="DESIGNONLYFF" type="radio" name="print"/></label>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XHCkc/  thanks // btw `toggle()` is actually working like `toggle()` should in this demo but on my local setup it appears to keep the `div` hidden if either input is selected (which is what I want) but it breaks if you click fast on...

Comment: Just noticed that if I do the show/hide as it is commented in my code it works right on jdfiddle, but it doesn't work right on my local setup..

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the problem.. just changed `(this)` to `'.option:checked'`

Comment: Great, I was checking your demo. Please post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind all -  I figured out the problem.. just changed `(this)` to `.option:checked`  now it works right. Thanks anyway! :)